ECS Taskrole is not allowed to assume itself
I have a next container as an ECS task. With this I want to read and write to/from S3.
To avoid to use credentials I added the taskrole to the ENV for this container. The taskrole was generate with CDK and has "S3FullAccess".
ROLE_NAME is arn:aws:iam::426003470206:role/rolenameA
In the code I added:
let s3Client: S3Client;

let temp_credentials: any = {};
async function loginRole() {
  const stsClient = new STSClient({ region: process.env.S3_REGION });
  temp_credentials = await stsClient.send(
    new AssumeRoleCommand({
      RoleArn: process.env.ROLE_NAME,
      RoleSessionName: "FrontendSession",
      DurationSeconds: 3600,
    })
  );

  s3Client = new S3Client({
    region: process.env.S3_REGION,
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: temp_credentials.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: temp_credentials.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: temp_credentials.Credentials.SessionToken,
    },
  });
}

if (process.env.ROLE_NAME != undefined) {
  setInterval(() => {
    loginRole();
  }, 3_600_000);
  loginRole();
} else {
  s3Client = new S3Client({
    region: process.env.S3_REGION,
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.MINIO_USER!,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.MINIO_PASS!,
    },
  });
}

But now, I get the error message:
AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/rolenameA/608fdb15fdfb418ea955e6c117245735 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::426003470206:role/rolenameA

608fdb15fdfb418ea955e6c117245735 is the task id where the container runs.
In all the role cannot assume the role from the container (task)?
The policy trusted relationship is:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

With Policies:
AmazonS3FullAccess
AmazonSQSFullAccess
NextAppContainerTaskRoleDefaultPolicy31CD40AE

If I use a common technical user and the accesskey (MINIO_USER) and secretkey (MINIO_PASS), everything works well. With the new code where I use the taskrole I get this error message above. Anything I missed here?

For those who have similar problems, my solution was very easy. Because my CDK create a TaskRole for the ECS Task, the role exists and I do not need to assume any role. Just use
let s3Client: S3Client;

let temp_credentials: any = {};
async function loginRole() {
  s3Client = new S3Client(null);
}

The Task is authorized and I can access S3 with an ease.
